# Generate problem details inside exception filter in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

The `ControllerBase` class has this very handy [`Problem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.problem?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method that automatically generates [RFC7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) error responses. We just have to specify the title and the status code and the `Problem` method will fill in the rest (E.G. Type = URI reference [RFC3986]).

Now, I am designing a global exception filter that will return error responses based on the exception encountered. But I also want to generate errors in the RFC7807 format. By itself, the [`ProblemDetails` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-6.0) cannot generate values on its own. I would like to be able to just provide the Title and status code and not care about other values. I will not be able to use `ControllerBase.Problem` since errors might occur even before controllers are created.

Is there a way to automatically generate a `ProblemDetails` object inside and exception filter? I am using ASP.NET Core 6.0.

Comment: You might be interested in the [Problem Details Middleware](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails/) developed by [Kristian Hellang](https://twitter.com/khellang). You can read about it in [this blog post by Andrew Lock](https://andrewlock.net/handling-web-api-exceptions-with-problemdetails-middleware/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out.

The [ControllerBase](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs) class has this:

```
_problemDetailsFactory = HttpContext?.RequestServices?.GetRequiredService<ProblemDetailsFactory>();
```

It seems that an implementation of ProblemDetailsFactory is being injected. So in my ExceptionFilter, I just do:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;

public class ApiErrorsFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    private ProblemDetailsFactory _problemDetailsFactory;

    public ApiErrorsFilter(ProblemDetailsFactory problemDetailsFactory) => _problemDetailsFactory = problemDetailsFactory;

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var exception = context.Exception;
        var httpContext = context.HttpContext;

        // sample response
        var problemDetails = _problemDetailsFactory.CreateProblemDetails(httpContext, statusCode: 500, title: "API error" );
        context.Result = new ObjectResult(problemDetails){
            StatusCode = problemDetails.Status
        };

        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }

}
```

This is good enough for me, but feel free to add more answers/comments if there is a better way.